# Tkinter scrollbar not working: dataframe display using grid

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, scrollbar

I am trying to display a pandas dataframe in a scrollable tkinter grid, but the scrollbars are not functioning. Below is my code.

```
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, borderwidth=0)

vbar=Scrollbar(root,orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

hbar=Scrollbar(root,orient=HORIZONTAL)
hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)   
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

frame = Frame(canvas)
frame.pack(side=TOP)
canvas.create_window(0,0,anchor='nw',height=300,width=300,window=frame)

for r in range(df.shape[0]-20):
    for c in range(df.shape[1]):
        Label(canvas, text=str(df.iloc[r,c]), borderwidth=1).grid(column=c*2, row=r*2)
        #tkinter.ttk.Separator(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL).grid(column=c*2, row=r*2+1, sticky='ew')
        #tkinter.ttk.Separator(frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=c*2+1, row=r*2, sticky='ns')


root.mainloop()
```

"df" is a pandas dataframe. When I run this code, the data displays in a window, but the scrollbars are stationary items which do not interact with the window. Additionally, when I uncomment the //'ed lines, the code seems to run forever, making my think these lines somehow take enormous amounts of time.

Comment: The canvas can’t scroll widgets added with `grid`, `pack`, or `place`.

Comment: is there a way to scroll widgets in a grid? atlernatively, is there a good way to make a scrollable table from a dataframe?